# Want to do the Anchor for oculus quest In MRTK

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus, mrtk

I got a project that is for hololens and use vuforia to detect the object. But I want to convert it to **oculus quest 2**. It is for MRTK and I want to keep it because a lot of function on it.But there is a probelm that oculus cannot use camera for detection. So I try to use the function named "spatial Anchor" to make my virtual object to align on it.And i want to try this.But after two days it still got problem.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXvykgvJP7I

I tried to follow this but some of the function said that didn't work.
Because i really don't know how to use it.

I tried this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpatialAnchorsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    //OVRPlayerController controller;
    [SerializeField]GameObject anchorobject;
    [SerializeField] ulong id;
    OVRSpatialAnchor anchor;


    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(createanchor());
        
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V))
        {
            //OVRPlugin.CreateSpatialAnchor();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator createanchor()
    {

        var anchor = gameObject.AddComponent<OVRSpatialAnchor>();
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => anchor.Created);
        var anchors = new HashSet<OVRSpatialAnchor> { anchor };

        //anchorobject = anchor.gameObject;
        

        yield return null;
    }


}
```

It give me the warning.
[Warning img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2vmF.png)

And it is the MRTK input setting for Passthrough
[MRTK setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVKL7.png)

i do something change in ovrcamerarig like this
[ovrcamera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD1Vn.png)

I want to make it use the oculus controller and press trigger to create an Anchor. And get the Anchor Transform.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

That error will appear when attempting to do it in the editor. You wont get that error on the device. The `OVRSpatialAnchor`'s only work on the device, not in-editor.

Try it on the device, you can use Unity's Android Logcat to look for the error while using the device to ensure it has worked.